# how to get result of order by on two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data

```
tab1
POS     NAME    DATE
1       abc   08-08-2014
2       def   08-08-2014
1       xyz   14-08-2014
2       mno   14-08-2014
3       pqr   08-08-2014
10      tuv   08-08-2014
```

Now I want the result like the following:

```
POS     NAME DATE
1       xyz 14-08-2014
2       mno 14-08-2014
1       abc 08-08-2014
2       def 08-08-2014
3       pqr 08-08-2014
10      tuv   08-08-2014
2       rns  08-08-2014
```

My logic is to display all the record ORDER by date IN DESC order and POS by ASC order

But if i run query with SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, `POS` ASC

then the following resultset is displaying:

```
POS     NAME DATE
1       xyz  14-08-2014
2       mno  14-08-2014
1       abc  08-08-2014
10      tuv  08-08-2014
2       def  08-08-2014
2       rns  08-08-2014
3       pqr  08-08-2014
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, `POS` ASC
```

does what you want.

However, as your POS column is a string (char or varchar) you have to cast it to a number:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, (`POS`+0) ASC
SELECT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, CAST(`POS` AS INT) ASC
```

This will cause the column to be converted to a number in all rows and, thus, resulting in a "worse" performance. You should consider to store POS as a number (integer).

Comment: In your first question you haven't pointed out that the ID column isn't a number but a string (char or varchar). You have to convert the POS column to a number, e.g. by adding +0 or some other casting. - This is bad for performance. Your POS-column should be a number for best performance (same applies to DATE column which should be a special date data type).

Comment: thanks MtTux I have changed the POS to INT and DATE to Date datatype and SELECT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, `POS` ASC is workingnot properly..I am editing the question kindly have a look

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select 
*
from 
myTable 

order by `date` desc, CAST(POS AS INT)
```

**Since ASC is by default, so havent mentioned in my answer**

Comment: its not working when the POS is 10 then its showing 10 after 1 then 2

Comment: @user3305327: Have updated my query, kindly check and let me know if it works